# PHP function to retrieve mysql table column not working

Tags: php, mysql, function

I have this PHP function that I want to use to retrieve a column, "username", from a table called "members". I have used the below function before, and had no problems. But now when I try to use it on a different project it won't work.

Here is the "functions.php" page code:

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
function getusername(){
        $query = "SELECT `username` FROM `members` WHERE `ID`=`".$_SESSION['user_id']."`";

        if($result = mysqli_query($con, $query)){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                return $row['username'];
            }
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
}
?>
```

On my login.php page I have a session variable that stores the user ID from the table in "$_SESSION['user_id']". I have echoed out the user ID so I know that the user ID is set.

On the page that I want the username echoed to, I have this snippet of code:

```
<?php echo getusername();?>
```

I also have the functions.php page "included" on the page where I want the username echoed to.

Comment: Could you give us a bit more of the code on the other page. Are there any errors?

Comment: @George are you referring to the other page that I need the username echoed to? Also, no errors

Comment: Remove the backticks from `".$_SESSION['user_id']."` and replace with single quotes `'".$_SESSION['user_id']."'` @user3084715

Comment: @Fred-ii- I appreciate the reply, I tried what you suggested and still nothing.

Comment: Is the session definitely started and the variable set? It could just be that you are putting in an ID that doesn't exist in the table

Comment: You also need to load `session_start();` and to assign it to a variable then, if you haven't done so already. @user3084715

Comment: remove the (`) the characters from the $query

Comment: My session_start(); is in my connection.php page which I "include" to. And I am sure a variable is set because I echoed out the "$_SESSION['user_id']" and it echoes a number corresponding to the correct user that I use to test the system.

Comment: @Tasos I have just tried that as well, still no change.

Comment: Hmm... try to run your query in phpmyadmin to see if it returns anything there

Comment: If the variable is set as, for example `$user_id=$_SESSION['user_id'];` then try doing `WHERE ID='$user_id'` keeping backticks around `ID` of course.

Comment: @George how do you suggest I run the query in phpmyadmin, the only reason that I am asking is because of the $_SESSION['user_id']; won't be set. Isn't that correct?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I just tried your suggestion, and unfortunately nothing.

Comment: It should work. That's how I do it myself.

Comment: SELECT `username` FROM `members` WHERE `ID`=1 but replace 1 for an actual id

Comment: It's time to `var_dump();` then. `var_dump($_SESSION['user_id']);`

Comment: @George I just ran that in phpmyadmin and it did in fact return my username.

Comment: echo your query and see what the result is

Comment: Thanks all, the below answer worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $con isn't set inside your function, so mysqli won't work. Additionally you're using backticks around the value you're searching for `$_SESSION['user_id']` backticks are for column names, you should use `'` around values.

try it like this:

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
function getusername($con){
   $query = "SELECT `username` FROM `members` WHERE `ID`='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
   if($result = mysqli_query($con, $query)){
       $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
       mysqli_free_result($result);
       return $row['username'];
   }
}
?>
```

Then call it passing `$con` to the function:

```
 $username=getusername($con);
```

On a side note your `mysqli_free_result` doesn't work if there are results as the `return` will stop the function. I updated the function a bit for it to work as you expect.

Comment: I appreciate the response, after trying this nothing has changed.